# Тип SSL сертификата для Geolocation в Chrome 50+

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps-api, ssl, https

Начиная с 50 хрома, при попытке использования геолокации на HTTP сайтах, JS консоль сообщает что такая возможность заблокирована:

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure
>   origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your
>   application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See
>   https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

Какого типа сертификата будет достаточно для того чтобы использовать данную функцию?

Есть следующие типы сертификатов:

- самоподписанный
- подписанный не доверенным сертификационным центром (СЦ)
- подписанный доверенным сертификационным центром

В свою очередь последний делится еще на:

- Esential SSL
- Instant SSL
- SGC SSL-сертификат
- Обычный Wildcard
- EV (Extended Validation) сертификат
- EV Wildcard и EV SGC

насколько я понял, самоподписанный позволяет шифровать трафик и использовать протокол HTTPS, но никак удостоверяет того, что сайт на самом деле является сайтом, за который себя выдает

Essential SSL и Instant SSL уже каким-то образом должны удостоверяться сертификационным центром.

Для того чтобы использовать геолокацию в хроме, будет-ли достаточно самоподписанного сертификата?

официальная запись от гугла:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: По идее, должно быть достаточно любого сертификата, которому доверяет браузер пользователя. То бишь чтобы сайт по HTTPS открывался без уведомления о небезопасном соединении. Даже бесплатные варианты, вроде StartSSL, WoSign и CloudFlare подойдут.

Comment: Lets Encrypt подойдет? Под него есть такой мануал https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04